# Bluetooth Adapter Not Found (Samsung r580)

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I had installed blueman and rfkill but I can't see bluetooth adapter in rfkill list, I ve been searching for hours but I am too new to ubuntu and don't know what to do. Here is rfkill list output.

```
widmore@Widmore-PC:~$ rfkill list
0: samsung-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have tried systemctl enable blueeoth and systemctl start bluetooth

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by formatting the system. Again it is 18.04 but with minimal installations, after install, I couldn't see the driver then I installed new updates and shut down my computer. Later on the driver was installed and working perfectly.